# Travel Maps Creation/Integration

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We should offer a feature to create, or integrate travel maps (somewhat like [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/help/what_is_the_travel_map)). It will surely allow us to gain more insight into the destinations fellow members have traveled, and can help along with.

Comment: What do you mean by "travel map"? I don't think we should do route-planning but I do think an illustrative map in the side panel with a marker for every place mentioned in the question, answers, and comments would be super smooth. It could also be leveraged into a different use on our profile page I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are many sites with such feature already. Our point is a Q&A site, not the Plan-A-Trip site. If user wants to point out some travel plan, he can share the URL to the google maps or something.

Also Plan-A-Trip question are very uncertain, users provides many options, and this is not how I think this site should work.

Answer (score 2):

What may be interesting would be a ["world heat map"](https://www.google.co.id/search?q=heat%20maps&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=725&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI243wka7zxgIVY6mmCh0CMA5J#tbm=isch&q=world%20heat%20maps) indicating for what country/region of the world a given user is active on the forum.

ie. a user who is only active for questions related to Croatia would have all the countries greyed out except Croatia coming up in red.